# Image looks sharpen and not readable in Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: html, css, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I have a questioned about the image related issue.

I am using same HTML and CSS sniped use for tizen TV and web browser but it is displaying Sharpen image on tizen TV.

This issue  is occured when image size is larger than UI resolution or equal to resolution. The Image resolution is 1280*720.

My Tizen TV resolution is 1280*720 and I have TV from 2015 model group.

Comment: When it comes to resolution issues I recommend checking *config.xml* and *widget.info*, these two are responsible for adjusting widget dimensions. However I have trouble understanding the exact problem. I use large images on Tizen displays - if size is adjusted there is always some artifacting, however nowhere near to what you describe.

Comment: actully my image box where image is fit in 500x400 and image size is 1280x720 so when it is in 500x400 image box the image looks sharpen and can't readable if image is also in 500x400 then it's looks nice what is the problem i don't know